# Error with Axios in Express middleware - cant send headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I am having some trouble understanding why my code is not executing properly.  When using Axios in my middleware, I am getting:

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Here is my code (I'm using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#forEach) forEach):

```
app.post('/myApi', function (req, res, next) {
  _.forEach(things, (thing) => {
    axios.post(url, { data: thing })
    .then(()=>{
      // writing data to an excel file
    })
    .then(()=>{
      // need this next to go to next middleware, but it causes the error mentioned above
      next()
    })
  })
})
```

As you can see, I mention that I need to call
 `next()`, but I get the aforementioned error.

I tried making the anonymous Lodash forEach function `async` and applying an `await` on the `axiox.post`, but that didn't seem to work.  I am not sure *where* exactly the headers are being sent.  **What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the call to next() within a _forEach() function, it means that you're calling next() on each loop, hence the reason for the error you mentioned.

Comment: Yikes! I can't believe I didn't realize that!  How would I be able to wait until the loop is done before calling next?